# Supabase python API: Updating multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-py

So, I have a database and I would like to update multiple rows in one query using the python API for supabase
supabase = create_client(api_url,api_key)

So in the command below:
I have db the name of my database in Supabase, product_data_update a json payload that is containing the content of multiple rows, sku_list_update and store_id_update 2 colums that I use to know which rows I want to update.

```py
update_result = supabase.table(db).update(product_dataupdate).in('sku',sku_listupdate).in('store_id', store_id_update).execute()
```

But after using this command, it's not doing what I want because it only update the first row of product_data_update to every row in sku_list_update and store_id_update and not one row for each element on the two arrays.

I also tried to create a function that does the query on supabase, it works perfectly on supabase but if i want to use the rpc method on python, it does nothing no message of error but nothing updated in my supabase database.

Is there any method using those arguments (sku_list_update and store_id_list_update) in order to update mutiple rows in my supabase db that I'm connected to or other method aswell ?

Comment: Could you provide example values for `sku_listupdate` and `sku_listupdate`?